# strange uniq output on Mac

Tags: linux, uniq

Here is the input file and output, I think characters like c and g should not be output?

```
$ uniq c.txt
a
g
b
g
c
v
c
$ cat c.txt
a
g
b
b
g
g
c
v
c
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [uniq man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uniq.1.html):

> Repeated lines in the input will not be detected if they are not
>   adjacent, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.

```
macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ cat c.txt
a
g
b
b
g
g
c
v
c
macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ uniq c.txt
a
g
b
g
c
v
c
macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ sort -u c.txt
a
b
c
g
v
macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ sort c.txt | uniq
a
b
c
g
v
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I see you are using -u and without -u options, the purposes are?

Comment: BTW, for "Repeated lines in the input will not be detected if they are not adjacent, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.", this is for Mac only?

Comment: If your goal is to get a list of uniq lines from the text file, `sort -u filename` is all you need.  You can of course pipe the output of `sort` into `uniq` (as I showed in the last example) but it's an unnecessary system call.

Comment: @LinMa - `uniq` can also count the occurrences of repeated lines. This is one of the cases where uniq is useful that sort doesn't provide. `sort c.txt | uniq -c`.